# Почему пишет ошибку(TypeError: <lambda>() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Нужен был текст при нажатии на который открывается новое окно, но когда прописал:

```
    self.lb_stat = tk.Label(self, text='Изменить статус')
    self.lb_stat.place(x=1,y=1)
    self.lb_stat.configure(bg = 'gray60')
    self.lb_stat.bind('<Button-1>', lambda: stat(self))
```

Но выходит ошибка: `TypeError: <lambda>() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given`. Как я понял lambda принимает 0 аргументом но был дан один, но из-за чего выходит ошибка я не знаю

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Метод [bind при вызове функции-обработчика передает объект события](https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-events-and-bindings.htm) поэтому нужно в `lambda` указывать параметр:

```
self.lb_stat.bind('<Button-1>', lambda event: stat(self))
```